# How to deploy Umbraco 7.3.1 without backoffice

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, publish

Is there a standard way to deploy Umbraco without the backoffice?  Some other cmses call this Author / Publish.

I want to configure 2 sites, the `public` site which does not have a backoffice, and an `author` site which does have the backoffice.  Both of those sites will target the same database, but the `author` site will only be accessible from within an internal vpn.

The benefit of this approach is security.  If there is no backend available on the `public` site and it is essentially a read only copy of the site it is much harder to hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy the website on one of the servers without the /Umbraco or /Umbraco-client folders which will effectively remove the backoffice.  What you're really looking at is a load-balanced scenario.  Umbraco 7.3 makes this really easy and there's a fair bit of documentation available.

I would recommend taking a look at the Load Balancing documentation on https://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Server-Setup/Load-Balancing/ - it includes a "recipe" for previous versions along with a good guide on the pitfalls.

Comment: Thanks! This approach works well for seemingly everything but media.  Is there a recommended way to handle media syncing?

Comment: Yep - use a distributed file system or some other shared directory.  If you're using Azure, there's an UmbracoFileSystem plugin for Umbraco that allows you to store media in a central repository: https://our.umbraco.org/projects/collaboration/umbracofilesystemprovidersazure/